# Managing VoIP calls via AsterNET

Tags: c#, asterisk, asteriskami, asternet

I am kind of newbie in VoIP programming. Let's say I have two VoIP phones connected to the same server, and I want to detect when the call fires, caller's ID, call duration, ... etc.
I learned about AsterNET, but didn't find any good example to see the process.

I know that I need to connect using ManagerConnection to my server, but what to do furthermore I have no idea.

I will appreciate any idea, advice, tutorial, etc...

Thanks.

Comment: Some people vote down general questions like this one, don't take it too personally.

Comment: Well, there are those thinking "if 'no idea' includes not reading the documentation, rather do not program my friend".

Comment: His question is valid AsterNET has no documentation to speak of

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to Manager event for example :

```cs
void manager_Events(object sender, ManagerEvent e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Event : " + e.GetType().Name);
}
```

Comment: Do I need to somehow use AGI?

Comment: NO don't need to use AGI it will only send you manager events. You should have proper handler for handling events.